# How to run azure logic app workflow with parameters using any command line or script

Tags: bash, azure, powershell, azure-logic-apps

I have created azure logic app to restore database from one prod to dev and for multiple envs

Now I want to automate my logic app workflow to run using any script or command line eg: using bash, PowerShell or AZ cli with my input parameters Actual value in screenshot should change using powershell (dev, int, qa)

[image]

I tried with powershell using -parameter option but it doesn't work.

Comment: HTTP trigger is the way.

Answer (score 0):

To run with powershell, regardless of having an http trigger, you can use :

Start-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup11" -Name "LogicApp03" -TriggerName "Trigger22"

With an Http Triger you have the extra option to invoke through http

Comment: where is the option here to pass parameter of env

Comment: how do specify environment structure? Azure is divided in subscriptions with resource groups. I have one resource group per environment, so i can run the logic app in dev like this: 
Start-AzLogicApp -ResourceGroupName "rg-contoso-us" -Name "dev-contoso-logicapp" -TriggerName "Recurrence"   because i have my dev logic app under my dev resource group.   to pass parameters to the logi app using Start-AzLogicApp ther e is a parameter called "-Parameters": 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/src/LogicApp/LogicApp/help/Start-AzLogicApp.md#-parameters

Comment: I have attached screenshot in above question pls check , I want to overwrite Actual value of parameter using powershell

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with @Skin and @BrunoLucasAzure, if you are using http trigger you can follow below process:

Thanks,  @shelladmin

I have followed [Micrsosoft-Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.3) and ShellGeek [Blog](https://shellgeek.com/getenumerator-in-powershell/), and  have reproduced in my environment and got expected results as below:

```
Connect-AzAccount -subscriptionid "b82b8374c23f"
$params = @{
    dev = "RITHWIK"
    int = "BOJJA"
    qa = "CHOTU"
}


$uri = "https://prod-80.eastus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/6433d8adb2a94a5ba7311/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2ual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=heG1IPRsFx_VUtgA_cOGttk"
foreach ($param in $params.GetEnumerator()) {
    $uri += "&" + $param.Key + "=" + $param.Value
}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method POST
```

[image]

[image]